# How to pass content from .txt file as argument for bash command after an equal sign

Tags: bash, command-line, input

Instead of typing in the content of a public key I want to pass the content of it as an input. The command used is

```
ipa user-mod user --sshpubkey='ssh-rsa AAA ........'
```

This work.

When I do

```
ipa user-mod user --sshpubkey=`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
```

or other combinations I get an error.

> ipa: ERROR: command 'user_mod' takes at most 1 argument.

How can I convert the text file to a single argument after the equal sign?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to quote the command substitution to prevent the shell from splitting the output of the `cat` command into separate words on the characters in `$IFS` (space, tab, and newline by default) and to avoid having the shell perform filename globbing on each of those words.

In short,

```bash
ipa user-mod user --sshpubkey="`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`"
```

Or, using the newer and friendlier `$(...)` syntax and getting rid of `cat`:

```bash
ipa user-mod user --sshpubkey="$(<~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"
```

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)